# Select first 10 rows for every 5 of a unique column

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

In a Postgres DB, given the following simplified dataset of `orders`:

```
ID    STORE_ID    UPDATED_AT
1     "store-1"   2021-01-01
2     "store-2"   2021-01-02
3     "store-3"   2021-01-03
4     "store-1"   2021-01-04
5     "store-2"   2021-01-05
6     "store-3"   2021-01-06
...
1000  "store-1"    2021-02-05
```

How can I write a query to select the the **first 5 unique store id's**, and the **first 10 orders per store** ordered by oldest to newest, resulting in a maximum of 50 rows returned?
For example:

```
ID    STORE_ID    UPDATED_AT
1     "store-1"   2021-01-01
4     "store-1"   2021-01-04
...
13    "store-1"   2021-01-12

2     "store-2"   2021-01-02
5     "store-2"   2021-01-05
...
18    "store-2"   2021-01-08

3     "store-3"   2021-01-03
8     "store-3"   2021-01-12
...
22    "store-3"   2021-01-22
```

---

My goal is to process orders from oldest to newest, but process the oldest 10 orders per store as I can batch them with the Shopify API which would be more efficient.

For example, in my code I will combine it to something like:

```
{
  "store-1": [{ /* order */ }, { /* order */ }, { /* order */ }, ...], // Array of 10 orders
  "store-2": [{ /* order */ }, { /* order */ }, { /* order */ }, ...], // Array of 10 orders
  "store-3": [{ /* order */ }, { /* order */ }, { /* order */ }, ...], // Array of 10 orders
  "store-4": [{ /* order */ }, { /* order */ }, { /* order */ }, ...], // Array of 10 orders
  "store-5": [{ /* order */ }, { /* order */ }, { /* order */ }, ...], // Array of 10 orders
}
```

So I can run 5 API calls in parallel for each store.

I've tried multiple queries, including the following:

```sql
SELECT a.store_id FROM orders a
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT store_id FROM orders GROUP BY store_id ORDER BY MIN(updated_at) LIMIT 5) b
    ON a.store_id = b.store_id
    ORDER BY a.updated_at ASC;
```

But I cannot limit the rows to 10 per store ID

Comment: I would write procedural code for that, perhaps in the database.

Comment: It id not clear from the question what "first five storeids" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a8e5808c9a53648ff3c8e6f865de6e54)

```
SELECT
    o.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        store_id
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (store_id)    -- 1a
            store_id, updated_at
        FROM orders
        ORDER BY store_id, updated_at
    ) s
    ORDER BY updated_at                  -- 1b
    LIMIT 5
) s
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (                     -- 2
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM orders o
    WHERE o.store_id = s.store_id
    ORDER BY updated_at
    LIMIT 10
) o
```

1 a) Return only one record per store using `DISTINCT ON` b) Identify the top 5 stores ordering by the date.
2. These stores can be used in a lateral join to filter the orders per store, again using the `updated_at` order.

Comment: In your fiddle if you add `(0, 'zzz', '2020-01-01')` to the beggining of the insert statement.. I'd expect this to be in the results as it has the earliest date, but it does not because the name starts with z

Comment: You're right. That's because of the ordering by store name. I changed this here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=77491e55e687bbdaf6df697069bc9880

Comment: Your recent edit to the code snippet seems promising.. let me do a few more tests :)

Answer (score 1):

```sql
with st as
(
 select distinct store_id 
 from orders 
 order by <your business rule here> 
 limit 5
)
select st.store_id, l.updated_at 
from st 
cross join lateral
(
 select updated_at
 from orders o
 where o.store_id = st.store_id
 order by updated_at desc
 limit 10
) l;
```

Comment: What should I put in `<your business rule here>`? I tried `ORDER BY updated_at ASC` but it errors with `for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

Comment: Also, I'm not sure where `odate` is coming from

Comment: I've updated the query at the bottom of my question which shows where I'm at.

Comment: My mistake. `odate` becomes `l.updated_at`. The `st` CTE shall be the one suggested by @SMan.

Answer (score 1):

One more possible query:

```
select ID,    STORE_ID,    UPDATED_AT
from (
  select 
      orders.* ,
      row_number() over (partition by STORE_ID order by UPDATED_AT desc) rn_order,
      dense_rank() over(order by STORE_ID) store_rank
  from orders
  order by STORE_ID
) ranked 
where store_rank <= [count srores] and rn_order <= [count orders per store];
```

[PostgreSQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=ad1f1c0270c3bff2faabcc08a995fef0&php_version=null&sql_version=psql12)